# Inverse of $f(x)=x^n(1-x)^k$

Tags: special-functions, inverse, inverse-function

I am trying to find an inverse of a function
\begin{align}
f(x)=x^n(1-x)^k, x \in (0,1)
\end{align}
where $n$ and $k$ are some positive integers.

I know that his function doesn't have a 'pure' inverse. However, it should have upper and lower branches.

Also, the inverse cannot be written in terms of elementary functions. Therefore, it has to be written in terms of some generalized functions like the Lambert-W function.

**Question:** Does $f$ have an inverse in terms of some generalized functions?

Comment: Some special cases are straightforward at least, for example for $n=k$ we have $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\sqrt[n]{x}}$ for $x\in [0,\frac{1}{2^{2n}}]$

Comment: A straightforward observation: $f$ has a unique maximum on $[0,1]$ at $x=\frac{n}{n+k}$, so two branches should suffice.

Comment: Well, your function is certainly a polynomial : $$x^n(1-x)^k=\sum_{m=0}^{k}{}_m\mathrm{C}_k(-1)^mx^{m+n}$$
Therefore finding an inverse function would equate to finding roots $y$ of the polynomial equation $$\left(\sum_{m=0}^{k}{}_m\mathrm{C}_k(-1)^my^{m+n}\right)-x=0$$
Which in general is quite difficult and I doubt there is even some sort of special function to write the solution in terms of.

Comment: Thank you. I think you have a good point here.

Answer (score 2):

The Lagrange inversion formula gives
$$a_i = \frac 1 {i!} \left. \frac {d^{i - 1}} {dy^{i - 1}}
 \left( \frac y {f(y)^{1/n}} \right)^{\! i} \, \right|_{y = 0} =
\frac 1 {i!} \left( \frac {i k} n \right)_{\! i - 1}, \\
f^{-1}(y) = \sum_{i \geq 1} a_i y^{i/n} =
y^{1/n} \hspace {1.5px} {_2 \hspace {-1px} \Psi_2} {\left( y^{1/n} \middle|
 {(1, 1), (\frac k n, 1 + \frac k n) \atop
  (2, 1), (\frac k n, \frac k n)} \right)},$$
where $(b)_i$ is the rising factorial and $\Psi$ is the Fox-Wright function. The second branch taking the values in $(0, 1)$ is $1 - f^{-1}(y)$ with $n$ and $k$ interchanged.

Comment: I have a few questions:  what is $( \cdot)_{i-1}$?   Second, you say values are interchanged, do you mean this $f_2^{-1}(y) =1- 
y^{1/k} \hspace {1.5px} {_2 \hspace {-1px} \Psi_2} {\left( y^{1/k} \middle|
 {(1, 1), (\frac n k, 1 + \frac n k) \atop
  (2, 1), (\frac n k, \frac n k)} \right)}$

Comment: @Boby $(\cdot)_v$ is the [Pochhammer symbol](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwioyK_r4fv7AhVkVjUKHWQtAGEQFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmathworld.wolfram.com%2FPochhammerSymbol.html&usg=AOvVaw3Qsm6mExpMC4NGYi2sc2ie)

Comment: Maybe it is possible to simplify into $\,_1\Psi_1$ like the solution for $x^v+ax+b=0$?